# Explanation of the meeting between Gus and Don Eladio

Tags: breaking-bad, plot-explanation

Why was [Max Arciniega](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Max_Arciniega) the only one killed in the meeting between him, Gud Fring & Don Eladio?

In episode 4.08 Don Eladio says to Gus:

> ‘we know who you are, that’s the only reason why you’re still alive.’

Can someone explain why Gus was spared?

[image]